# ffmpeg: unexpected behavior during extraction of frames with specified interval

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, video-encoding

I need to obtain snapshots from a video with 30 seconds interval.
It is recommended in the Internet to use the following command:

`ffmpeg -i <video_file_path> -vf fps=1/30 <directory>/%04d.jpg`

It works, but with a 15 seconds offset from file beginning. Tested with different video formats:
- expected: image taken on 30 s -> 1 m -> 1 m 30 s, etc.;
- actual result: 15 s -> 45 s, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47671742

Comment: Thank you @Gyan, you've helped a lot. I've spent more, than a day experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gyan, I've found a solution, using the link.

There are several *round* options, which may be used with *fps* the following way:

`-vf fps=1/30:round=<value>`

The following values are allowed: *zero*, *inf*, *down*, *up*, *near*.

I've tested all these options on a video with 1m 46s length.
Results:
 - **zero** and **down**: images taken on 30s, 1m, 1m 30s - 3 images in total;
 - **inf** and **up** do the same, adding one snapshot of the very beginning of the video - 4 images in total;
- **near** (default value): 15s, 45s, 1m 15s, 1m 45s - 4 images in total.

Going to use *zero* or *down*, as I haven't found any difference and result is what I need.

More information read here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps-1